# Problems with HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit

I'm trying use HtmlUnit to submit a form, there are two select in my form, when i selected the first select, his call a function ajax and load the second select, follow my code:

```
HtmlPage page5 = anchor.click();

HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("form1");

HtmlSelect state = form.getSelectByName("ddlMarca");

state.setSelectedAttribute(state.getOptionByValue("56"), true);

state.fireEvent(Event.TYPE_CHANGE);

HtmlSelect city = form.getSelectByName("ddlModelo");

for (HtmlOption option : city.getOptions()) {
 System.out.println("city : "+option.asText()+" valor: " +option.getValueAttribute());
}
```

I'm using the method fireEvent to call event change, but does't work, How I can do this event work?

Answer (score 1):

It may be working but you're not giving the browser time to make the ajax call, get a response and edit the dom. If the page makes an ajax call after firing the change event, try letting the page wait for a moment before checking again.

I haven't tested the below code so I can't say for certain this will solve you're issues, but I have used this technique to solve a similar issue.

You'll have to find something on the page that changes when the ajax call is completed for this to work. From the above question I'm assuming that changing one select populates the 2nd select box.

```
state.fireEvent(Event.TYPE_CHANGE);

//try 20 times to wait .5 second each for filling the page.
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
       if (condition_to_happen_after_js_execution) {
           break;
       }
       synchronized (page) {
           page.wait(500);
       }
}

HtmlSelect city = form.getSelectByName("ddlModelo");

for (HtmlOption option : city.getOptions()) {
 System.out.println("city : "+option.asText()+" valor: " +option.getValueAttribute());
}
```

Example pulled from: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork